# ORA-01722: invalid number in Oracle update

Tags: oracle

how to update emp_name using implicit cursor in oracle.

for this purpose i wrote a program in pl/sql

```
 DECLARE  
     var_names VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      UPDATE emp
      SET emp_name= emp_name +'garu';
      IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('None of the salaries where updated');
      ELSIF SQL%FOUND THEN
      var_names:=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line('Salaries for ' || var_names|| 'employees are updated');
      END IF; 
    END;
```

but showing error,that is

```
Error report:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 4
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You do not use `+`(plus)  to concatenate sting literals, in oracle you use two vertical bars `||` - string concatenation operator or `concat` function. 1) `set emp_name= emp_name || 'garu';` or 2) `emp_name = concat(emp_name,'garu');`

Comment: i tried what u tolled but it showing error  'SQL command not properly ended'

Comment: "DECLARE  
     var_names VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
      UPDATE emp
      SET emp_name= emp_name = concat(emp_name,'garu') ;
      IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('None of the salaries where updated');
      ELSIF SQL%FOUND THEN
      var_names:=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line('Salaries for ' || var_names|| 'employees are updated');
      END IF; 
    END;"

Comment: `SQL command not properly ended`. Of course it's not. Take a closer look at this line `SET emp_name= emp_name = concat(emp_name,'garu')` in your code. Looks suspicious.

Comment: @user2775287, It looks like there is error in your update query.
Try like this, UPDATE emp SET emp_name = concat(emp_name,'garu') ;

Answer (score 2):

In your `SET` clause you are using an arithmetic operator between non-numeric operands.

The [concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators003.htm#sthref818) in Oracle is `||`, not `+`.

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator defined by the SQL standard and nearly every DBMS uses it.

Answer (score 2):

`+` cannot be used for concatenation.. You have to either use `concat` function or `||`